# How to conditionally use an inner join?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm working on a CTE (probably not relevant), and I have two possible inner joins, but the second one should only be used if the first one is empty (it could be used anyway, in fact, IT MUST be executed alongside the first inner join:

```sql
with recursive "test_table" as (
     select stuff from test_table 
          inner join base_table bt on bt.property = test_table.property // THIS MIGHT FIND A SET OF ROWS
          inner join base_table bt2 on bt2.id = test_table.innerProperty // THIS MIGHT FIND SOME OTHER ROWS
)
```

The thing is, this doesn't work, as it brings 0 rows, but if I execute the first inner join OR the second one separetely, it works just fine. I tried using an `OR` but it loops infinitely.

I'm using postgres 13, btw

Comment: Try `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: And remove the <mysql> tag, since you're using Postgresql.

Comment: LEFT JOIN and COALESCE(). And, because of the slave tables may contain duplicates, apply DISTINCT.

Comment: Left join did not work, but I'm not sure how to use it alongside coalesce

Comment: @RinnieR -- you want a left join on both BT and BT2.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: I actually think your use case needs the use of lateral joins, not outer joins. Please add some rows of sample data and the expected result so we can understand the case and help you.

Comment: I don't understand where in that query you would place an OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming some sample data on your structures:

```
create table test_table (
  stuff text,
  property text,
  innerProperty text
);

create table base_table (
  property text,
  id text,
  stuff text
);

insert into test_table values
('foot1', 'foot', 'ball'),
('foot2', 'ultimate', 'frisbee'),
('foot3', 'base', 'ball'),
('foot4', 'nix', 'nein');

insert into base_table values
('foot', 'foot', 'feet'),
('flat', 'ball', 'pancake'),
('flit', 'frisbee', 'float');
```

I think in general using left outer joins instead of inner joins is the basis of the solution:

```
select t.stuff, bt.stuff, bt2.stuff
from
  test_table t 
  left join base_table bt on bt.property = t.property
  left join base_table bt2 on bt2.id = t.innerProperty
where
  bt.property is not null or bt2.id is not null
```

Where the `where` clause mimics basically what you are trying to do -- you want a match from one or the other.

However, this yields these results:

```
foot1   feet    pancake    <- Bt2.stuff should be empty if BT matches?
foot2           float
foot3           pancake
```

My understanding is that if there is a match on `bt` then you don't want to even evaluate the second join -- make `bt2` conditional on NO match from `bt`.  If that is the case you can simply change the join condition on `bt2` from this:

```
left join base_table bt2 on bt2.id = t.innerProperty
```

to this:

```
left join base_table bt2 on bt2.id = t.innerProperty and bt.property is null
```

Meaning, don't do the BT2 join if BT was successful.

Which you can see skips removes bt2.stuff = pancake from the query:

```
foot1   feet    
foot2           float
foot3           pancake
```

Let me know if this is what you had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

`INNER JOIN` only keeps rows that meet the join condition on both sides, and in that sense it acts like a filter.  When you have two inner joins, you are performing this filter twice, so when you get 0 rows returned it means that no row meets **both** of the 2 join conditions you used.

If I understand your question correctly, rather than do 2 inner joins, you should opt for 2 left joins and use `COALESCE` to set the condition that when the first join didn't produce any results, use the second join.

```
SELECT
    -- If bt.yourcolumn is NULL, 
    -- because the JOIN condition was not met, use b2.yourcolumn
    COALESCE(bt.yourcolumn, bt2.yourcolumn) AS yourcolumn
FROM ... --use left joins
```

Comment: But how do I apply that to my query? I've never heard of coalesce before and I can't seem to understand how that works